Issue regarding an out of range problem in my optimization problem OpenMDAO
In my project, I am trying to optimize the Volume of an airship regarding mission requirements and to do so I have the calculation of the weight through out 2 methods and then I substract one to the other and the objective is to minimize this subtraction.
In one of the method for the weight I have to compute the Reynolds Number Re :
Re = ((lb*Vs*pho_cruise_alt)/mu)

But at every iteration the code stop running and can't find the minimum because at some point Re become equal to 0 and when I use it to compute the friction coefficient :
Cf = (0.455/(log10(Re)**2.58))

So after this I checked by printing Re for each iteration and also printing lb because it is the only variable in the formula of Re and so for at the beginning Re and lb have normal value and at some point it drop to 0 directly like every other variables.
I don't know how to deal with this. Why does it drop in one iteration ? Is there a method to try and avoid this ? Maybe is it possible to just force the model to not reach 0 ?
Here is my code :
import openmdao.api as om
from math import *

AR_tails = 1.0
pho_cruise_alt = 0.00211 #in slug/ft3 4000ft
pho_max_alt = 0.001876 #in slug/ft3 8000ft
pho_sea_level = 0.002377 #in slug/ft3
Vs = 84.5 #en f/s
mu = 3.66*10**(-7) #in poise
tc = 0.15 #no unit
nb_lobes = 3 #no unit a voir si on veut mettre ca dasn l'optimisation
range = 1000 #in nautical miles
NE = 4 #number of engine, no unit, a voir par la suite avec la reliaility
BR = 0.7 #no unit
BSFC = 0.48 #Brake Specific fuel consumption, no unit
Payload = 40000 #in lb
FS = 4 #Security factor, no unit
Manufacturing_factor = 1.2 #no unit
nb_septum = 2 #no unit,a voir si je modifie ca pour permettre de le modif
Faf = 1.26 #account for the external attach fitting, no unit
Seaming_factor = 1.06 #no unit
nb_ball = nb_lobes*2 #6 #no unit
Fpsq = 1.0 #account for the fabrication of the tail in lightweight structural material, no unit
surface_CS = 0.2 #percentage of the CS on the tail surface, no unit
Fact = 0.79 #no unit
Finstall = 1.15 #account for the installation of actuators, no unit
lec = 150 #account for the length of control cable for the engines, in ft
Nb_prop = 4 #no unit
Nbl = 3 #no unit
Kp = 31.92 #no unit
nt = 2 #number of fuel tank, no unit
Integral_tank = 0 #percentage of fuel tank that are integral, no unit
Npad = 3 #number of pads for ACLS, no unit
Vsr = 4 #landing sink rate, in f/s
Wcomputer = 250 #account for the weight of the computer, it's estimated, in lb
Wavionics = 250 #account for the weight of instruments, in lb
Wfs = 470 #account for the weight of fuel system, in lb
Kelect = 33.73 #account for a coef that depend on the type of range flight, no unit
np = 0.65 #propeller efficiency, no unit


class Geometry(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('V',val=1000000.0)
        self.add_input('FR',val=3.0)
        self.add_output('V23',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('de',val=3.0)
        self.add_output('lb',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('dc',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('w',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('ht',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('AR',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Swet_body_lobed',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('SHT',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('SVT',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Wg',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Wh0',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Wh1',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('total_fuel',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Woe',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Cd0',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('K',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('L', val=1.0)

    def setup_partials(self):
        # Finite difference all partials.
        self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

    def compute(self,inputs,outputs):
        V = inputs['V']
        FR = inputs['FR']

        outputs['V23'] = V23 = V**(2/3)
        outputs['de'] = de = ((6*V)/(FR*pi))**(1/3) #equivalent diameter of body of revolution
        outputs['lb'] = lb = FR*de
        outputs['dc'] = dc = (de/(-0.0178*nb_lobes**2+0.361*nb_lobes+0.575))
        outputs['w'] = w = (1+nb_lobes)*(dc/2)
        outputs['ht'] = ht = dc
        outputs['AR'] = AR = ((4*w**2)/(pi*lb*w))

        p = 1.6075
        Swet_body_ellipsoid = pi*((lb**p*w**p+lb**p*ht**p+w**p*ht**p)/3)**(1/p)
        if nb_lobes == 1:
            p_ellipsoid = 2*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = 2*pi*(dc/2)
        if nb_lobes == 2:
            p_ellipsoid = 2.525*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = (8*pi*(dc/2))/3
        if nb_lobes == 3:
            p_ellipsoid = 3.084*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = (10*pi*(dc/2))/3
        if nb_lobes == 4:
            p_ellipsoid = 3.663*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = (12*pi*(dc/2))/3
        if nb_lobes == 5:
            p_ellipsoid = 4.254*pi*(dc/2)
            p_lobes = (14*pi*(dc/2))/3
        outputs['Swet_body_lobed'] = Swet_body_lobed = (p_lobes/p_ellipsoid)*Swet_body_ellipsoid
        CHT = -0.0051*(1000000/V)+0.0717
        outputs['SHT'] = SHT = CHT*(V23*lb)/(0.38*lb)
        CVT = -0.0049*(1000000/V)+0.0641
        outputs['SVT'] = SVT = CVT*(V23*lb)/(0.38*lb)
        Cd0tab = []
        q = (1/2)*pho_cruise_alt*Vs**2
        Re = ((lb*Vs*pho_cruise_alt)/mu)
        print('V',V)
        print('lb',lb)
        print(Re)
        try:
            Cf = (0.455/(log10(Re)**2.58))
        except ValueError as e:
            raise om.AnalysisError('Re out of range')
        FF3D_body = 1+(1.5/FR**1.5)+(7/FR**3)
        Cd0_body = ((FF3D_body*Cf*Swet_body_lobed)/V23)
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0_body)
        FF_tail = 1+1.2*tc+100*tc**4
        ctail = ((AR_tails*SHT*0.5)**0.5+(AR_tails*SVT*0.5)**0.5)/2
        Re_tail = (ctail*Vs*pho_cruise_alt)/mu
        cf_tail = 0.455/(log10(Re_tail)**2.58)
        Swet_tail = 2.2*(SHT+SVT)
        Cd0_tail = (FF_tail*cf_tail*Swet_tail)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0_tail)
        #Add every Cd0 for each part of the airship, check what we choose in the end
        Cd0cab = (0.108*Cd0_body*V23+7.7)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0cab)
        Cd0eng = NE*4.25/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0eng)
        Cd0engcooling = NE*(2*10**(-6)*V+4.1)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0engcooling)
        Cd0engmount = (0.044*Cd0_body*V23+0.92)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0engmount)
        Cd0cables = (9.7*10**(-6)*V+10.22)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0cables)
        Cd0ACLS = 0.0002
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0ACLS)
        Cd0_int = (4.78*10**(-6)*V)/V23
        Cd0tab.append(Cd0_int)
        outputs['Cd0'] = Cd0 = sum(Cd0tab)
        outputs['K'] = -0.0145*(1/AR)**4 + 0.182*(1/AR)**3 - 0.514*(1/AR)**2 + 0.838*(1/AR) - 0.053
        if nb_lobes == 1:
            Nl = 2
        if nb_lobes == 2:
            Nl = 2.25
        if nb_lobes == 3:
            Nl = 2.4
        if nb_lobes == 4:
            Nl = 2.5
        if nb_lobes == 5:
            Nl = 2.54
        outputs['K'] = K = outputs['K']/Nl
        outputs['L'] = L = 0.0646*V*(pho_max_alt/pho_sea_level)
        Wlanding = L/BR
        outputs['Wh1'] = Wh1 = Wlanding - L
        A = (326*np)/(BSFC*sqrt(K*Cd0))
        B = q*V23*sqrt(Cd0/K)
        outputs['Wh0'] = Wh0 = B*tan((range/A)+atan(Wh1/B))
        fuel_burned = Wh0-Wh1
        fuelres = fuel_burned*0.05
        outputs['total_fuel'] = fuel_burned+fuelres
        Wzf = (L/BR)-fuelres
        outputs['Woe'] = Wzf - Payload
        outputs['Wg'] = Wlanding + fuel_burned

class aerodynamic(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('Wh0',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('V23',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Cd0',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('K',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('qmax',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Maxpower_perengine',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Dp',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('np_check',val=1.0)

    def setup_partials(self):
        self.declare_partials('*','*',method='fd')

    def compute(self,inputs,outputs):
        Wh0= inputs['Wh0']
        V23= inputs['V23']
        Cd0= inputs['Cd0']
        K= inputs['K']
        qmax = outputs['qmax']
        Maxpower_perengine = outputs['Maxpower_perengine']
        Dp= outputs['Dp']
        np_check= outputs['np_check']


        L_aero = Wh0
        qmax[...] = pho_sea_level*(((Vs*1.1)**2)/2)
        Clmax_power = (L_aero/qmax/V23)
        Drag = (Cd0+K*Clmax_power**2)*qmax*V23
        Maxpower_perengine[...] = (Vs*1.1)*(Drag/np/NE/550)
        Cs = ((pho_sea_level*Vs**5)/Maxpower_perengine/550/10**2)**(1/5) #10 correspond a une rotation max pour le propeller speed and pho is in slug/ft3
        J = 0.156*Cs**2+0.241*Cs+0.138
        Dp[...] = ((Vs)/10)/J
        np_check[...] = 0.139*Cs**3-0.749*Cs**2+1.37*Cs+0.0115

class second_weight_estimation(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('qmax',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('ht',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('V',val=1000000.0)
        self.add_input('SHT',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('SVT',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Swet_body_lobed',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('dc',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('lb',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Maxpower_perengine',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Dp',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('total_fuel',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Woe',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Wh0',val=1.0)
        self.add_input('Wh1',val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Wg2',val=1.0)

    def setup_partials(self):
        self.declare_partials('*','*',method='fd')

    def compute(self,inputs,outputs):
        qmax = inputs['qmax']
        ht = inputs['ht']
        V = inputs['V']
        SHT = inputs['SHT']
        SVT = inputs['SVT']
        Swet_body_lobed = inputs['Swet_body_lobed']
        dc = inputs['dc']
        lb = inputs['lb']
        Maxpower_perengine = inputs['Maxpower_perengine']
        Dp = inputs['Dp']
        total_fuel = inputs['total_fuel']
        Woe = inputs['Woe']
        Wh0 = inputs['Wh0']
        Wh1 = inputs['Wh1']
        Wg2 = outputs['Wg2']

        Weight = []
        Pint = 1.2*qmax+0.0635*ht
        hull_fabric_load = FS*12*(Pint/144)*(dc/2)
        hull_fabric_density = 0.0085*hull_fabric_load+1.365
        Whull = hull_fabric_density*Manufacturing_factor*Faf*Swet_body_lobed/(16*9) #to convert each unit in yd2 and then go into lb
        Septum_fabric_load = 1.5*hull_fabric_load
        Septum_fabric_density = 0.0085*Septum_fabric_load+1.365
        side_body_area = 0.75 #percentage of envelope side body area
        Wseptum = nb_septum*Seaming_factor*Septum_fabric_density*side_body_area*pi*ht*(lb/4)/(16*9) #we have a formula for the body side area after side body area
        Wenv = Wseptum+Whull
        Weight.append(Wenv)
        Vball = V*((1/(pho_max_alt/pho_sea_level))-1)
        Sball = nb_ball*pi*(nb_lobes*((Vball/pi)/6))**(2/3)
        Wball = 0.035*Sball
        Weight.append(Wball)
        Wssf = Fpsq*(SHT+SVT)*Faf*(1-surface_CS)
        Wcs = Fpsq*(SHT+SVT)*surface_CS
        Wtail = Wcs+Wssf
        Weight.append(Wtail)
        Wact = Fact*Finstall*surface_CS*(SHT+SVT)
        Weng = NE*Maxpower_perengine**(0.7956)*4.848
        Weight.append(Weng)
        Wengmt = 0.64*Weng
        Weight.append(Wengmt)
        Wec = 60.27*(lec*(NE/100))**(0.724)
        Weight.append(Wec)
        Wstart = 50.38*((Weng/1000))**(0.459)
        Weight.append(Wstart)
        Wprop = Nb_prop*Kp*Nbl**(0.391)*(Dp*(Maxpower_perengine/1000))**(0.782)
        Weight.append(Wprop)
        Wft = 2.49*(total_fuel/6)**(0.6)*nt**(0.2)*NE**(0.13)*(1/(1+Integral_tank))**(0.3) #total fuel is divided by 6 which the weight in lb per gallon for aviation gas
        Weight.append(Wft)
        Wpress_syst = 0.02*Woe
        Weight.append(Wpress_syst)
        Ppad = Pint
        ACLS_area_landing = 3*(0.23*Wh1*(Vsr/(Npad*Ppad))) #we multiply it by 3 because 3 pads but the configuration can change some stuff and then modify the calculations
        ACLS_area_takeoff = Wh0/Ppad
        Wacls = 1.6*max(ACLS_area_landing,ACLS_area_takeoff)
        Weight.append(Wacls)
        Wvms = Wcomputer+Wavionics+Wact
        Weight.append(Wvms)
        Welect = Kelect * (Wfs+Wcomputer+Wavionics)**(0.51)  #maybe don't have this equation
        Weight.append(Welect)
        Wmsys = 0.05*Woe
        Weight.append(Wmsys)
        Wuf = 0.01*total_fuel
        Weight.append(Wuf)
        Wmargin = 0.06*Woe
        Weight.append(Wmargin)
        Woe2 = sum(Weight)
        Wg2[...] = Woe2 + total_fuel + Payload

class Optimization(om.Group):
    def setup(self):
        cycle = self.add_subsystem('cycle',om.Group(),
                                    promotes_inputs=['V','FR'],
                                    promotes_outputs=['Wg', 'Wg2', 'L', 'np_check'])
        cycle.add_subsystem('d1', Geometry(),
                            promotes_inputs=['V','FR'],
                            promotes_outputs=['Wg', 'L'])
        cycle.add_subsystem('d4', aerodynamic(),
                            promotes_outputs=['np_check'])
        cycle.add_subsystem('d5', second_weight_estimation(),
                            promotes_inputs=['V'],
                            promotes_outputs=['Wg2'])

        cycle.connect('d1.V23','d4.V23')
        cycle.connect('d1.lb','d5.lb')
        cycle.connect('d1.dc','d5.dc')
        cycle.connect('d1.ht','d5.ht')
        cycle.connect('d1.Swet_body_lobed','d5.Swet_body_lobed')
        cycle.connect('d1.SHT','d5.SHT')
        cycle.connect('d1.SVT','d5.SVT')
        cycle.connect('d1.Wh0','d4.Wh0')
        cycle.connect('d1.Wh0','d5.Wh0')
        cycle.connect('d1.Wh1','d5.Wh1')
        cycle.connect('d1.total_fuel','d5.total_fuel')
        cycle.connect('d1.Woe','d5.Woe')
        cycle.connect('d1.Cd0','d4.Cd0')
        cycle.connect('d1.K','d4.K')
        cycle.connect('d4.qmax','d5.qmax')
        cycle.connect('d4.Maxpower_perengine','d5.Maxpower_perengine')
        cycle.connect('d4.Dp','d5.Dp')

        # No feedback, not necessary
        # cycle.nonlinear_solver = om.NonlinearBlockGS()

        cycle.set_input_defaults('V',val=2)

        self.add_subsystem('obj', om.ExecComp('obj = Wg - Wg2'), promotes= ['obj','Wg','Wg2'])
        self.add_subsystem('c1', om.ExecComp('c1 = L/Wg'), promotes=['c1','L','Wg'])
        self.add_subsystem('c2', om.ExecComp('c2 = np_check'), promotes=['c2','np_check'])


prob = om.Problem()
prob.model = Optimization()

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['maxiter'] = 100
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-8

prob.model.add_design_var('V', lower=0, ref=1.0E6)
prob.model.add_design_var('FR', lower=0)
prob.model.add_objective('obj', ref=1.0E6)
prob.model.add_constraint('c1', lower=0, upper=1.0)
prob.model.add_constraint('np_check', lower=0.95*np, upper=1.05*np)

# Ask OpenMDAO to finite-difference across the model to compute the gradients for the optimizer
prob.model.approx_totals()

prob.setup()
prob.set_val('V',2000000)
prob.set_val('FR',3)

prob.run_driver()

Thanks in advance for reading everything and hope we can find a solution together

I can't comment on the validity of your model, but what if you a constraint to keep Re > 1 or some reasonable value of Re? You can also raise an Analysis Error if Re<=0, and some optimizers like SNOPT or IPOPT can handle it and steer away from the problem area.

Thanks but in fact I found another solution that was due to the model i tried to do, I was putting one of the design variable to 0 and physically that wasn't possible and so it was putting the optimization in a spot where Re was having the value of 0 and then making it impossible to solve but thanks for the answer
